# I am owner but get message that I don't own the app id

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to duplicate my app in the administration console, but receive the following error:

> **There were errors:** developer does not own the app id being forked

My gmail account is showing up as the "Owner" in the Permissions Tab.

Did anyone ever have the same experience? Any thoughts or advice on how to tackle this problem?

I already tried through inkognito mode in chrome like it is described here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8106

*Edit: 
I changed to two factor authentication 2 weeks ago. I just tried it with deactivated 2factorauth, it does nothing.*

Answer (score 1):

Do you own the name that it's trying to tie the duplicate to?

Check this by attempting to create an app with the same name before you attempt to duplicate, I guess.

Comment: theres a dilemma,
i can't create another appid, google wants me to authenticate myself over mobile number but then says my phonenumber was already used.

Of course it was used: to create the very first app i am trying to duplicate ...

Comment: You only need to authenticate your google account once with SMS, then it's done for ever. Once you have an account that can create 1 app engine application you can create up to 9 more on that same account. I create new apps here: https://appengine.google.com/ Otherwise I suspect some sort of account mix up on your side.

Comment: Yes Paul, thats what i thought. i created one in the last months or so and its up and running under https://victorsanwendung.appspot.com/ and it correctly shows the "Create Application" Button and the "9 more" indicator. But when i click, i get the SMS authentication again. 
Account mixup is impossible, i have only one and have been using it for years. Mobile number mixup is impossible, have been using it for years (e.g. victorsanwendung appid). But thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @vicwue can you fill the SMS issue form linked here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/sms#error

Comment: i already did, but thanks. i did also report a production issue.

Comment: @vicwue most likely you're are trying to create a new app with another domain and not your Gmail account.. right? That's why it asks you to provide the SMS verification again..

Comment: could you clarify that? i am trying to create another app/duplicate my first app with the standard appspot domain while being logged in to my gmail/google account.